# android google maps center of the camera location name

Tags: android, google-maps

hi guys i have a marker in the center of my map camera and i want to show where information of the place marker is right now i write this so far but its not working and here is the error

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getDeviceLocation();

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(cameraPosition.target.latitude,cameraPosition.target.longitude, 1);
                Address obj = addresses.get(0);
                String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("IGA", "Address" + add);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


    }
```

this is the error and its comes from List

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post the entire stack trace I can't really know which object is throwing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. But this sample code should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(cameraPosition.target.latitude,cameraPosition.target.longitude, 1);
        for(Address address : addresses){
            if(address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > -1){
                String add = address.getAddressLine(0);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("IGA", "Address" + add);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I've add a foreach loop for the `addresses` object. I see that you have put a max Address of 1 in your `getFromLocation()` method, but if you change it to a higher number then this code should still work for all `Addresses`.

I've also put a check to see if the `address` actually has a value at `getAddressLine(0)` by checking `getMaxAddressLineIndex()` is bigger than -1. It is the index not count.  `getMaxAddressLineIndex()` will return -1 if it is empty.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me please can you tell me what should i post more? cause this code is not working too this time there is no crash and no toast or Logs

Comment: thanks a lot now its working i have another question and its so helpful if you can help me about it can i change the language of this locations?im from Iran and i want this location addreses to be farsi

Comment: i see farsi locations on iranian apps

Comment: No, I do not want to disturb you. I searched for myself but I did not find it. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: @razaAmini :: I see you have already tried `new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());`  and I don't think `Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), new Locale("fa","IR"));` will work. Good luck finding the right language locale.

Comment: thanks a lot im so new in android programming and i cant write english so well and i did not find any local language sites to explain this thank you so much man sorry for disturb you